# Triple integral - converting to cylindrical coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration

In part A of my question I was asked to compute the Jacobian associated with the substitution $(x,y,z)=(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta,z).$

I did this and found the answer to be $r$.

Next I'm asked to compute $\iiint (x^2+y)z \ dx dy dz $.

I'm also told that the region of integration is $$\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3:0 \leq x^2+y^2 \leq1 \text{ and } 0\leq z \leq 1 \}$$

I would have said I need to compute $$\int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^1(r^2 \cos^2\theta+r\sin\theta)z \ rdrd\theta dz$$

However, the solution says it should be $$\int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^1(r^2 \cos^2\theta+r\sin\theta) \ rdrd\theta dz$$

Why is mine incorrect? I don't understand why they have lost a $z$ in the integral.

The correct answer to the problem is $\frac{\pi}{4}.$

This is my working so far:

$$\int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^1r^3 \cos^2\theta z+r^2\sin\theta z \ drd\theta dz$$

$$=\int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^{2\pi} \bigg[\frac{\cos^2\theta z r^4}{4}+\frac{\sin \theta z r^3}{3} \bigg] d\theta dz (\text{ between 0 and 1 })$$

$$=\int_{0}^1 \int_{}^{2\pi} \frac{\cos^2\theta z}{4}+\frac{\sin\theta z}{3} \ d\theta dz$$

$$\int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{z\cos2\theta}{8}+\frac{z}{8}+\frac{\sin\theta z}{3}$$

$$\int_{0}^1 \bigg[ \frac{z\sin2\theta}{16}+\frac{z\theta}{8}-\frac{\cos\theta z}{3}\bigg ] dz (\text{ between 0 and 2 pi })$$

$$\int_{0}^1 \frac{z\pi}{4} \ dz = \frac{\pi}{8}$$

The solution says the answer should be $\frac{\pi}{4}$, where have I gone wrong?

[image]

Comment: your answer is right maybe it is just a typo in problem statement

Comment: @K.K.McDonald I have used what I thought is correct but this is getting me a different answer to the solution. Are you sure mine is correct?

Comment: yes your answer is correct.

Comment: maybe the integrand of interest in problem were $\iiint (x^2+y) \ dx dy dz $ and $\iiint (x^2+y)z \ dx dy dz $ is a writing mistake and typo of the problem statement.

Comment: If you delete the $z$ from your steps you end up with $\int_{0}^1 \frac{\pi}{4} \ dz = \frac{\pi}{4}$ so its just a problem with your solution given not your answer

Comment: @K.K.McDonald I've attached an image of the solution to the exam question. Do you think it's incorrect then?

Comment: yea the problem is incorrect. the integral of question must be $\iiint (x^2+y) \ dx dy dz $

Comment: Note that you can add upper and lower limits after the brackets, e.g. `\left[...\right]_0^1` where you wrote "(between $0$ and $1$)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As stated in the comments, this appears to be a typo in the problem statement. Your work is correct, and the work in the image at the bottom is correct if you remove the $z$ from the initial integral.